# I need to reinstall Domino and I need a copy of “Notes/Domino 9.0.1 Feature Pack 10” Where is a download link?

Tags: lotus-domino, ibm-domino

I need to reinstall Domino and I need a copy of “Notes/Domino 9.0.1 Feature Pack 10” Where is a download link?

Searched online, cannot find working download link

Comment: Try asking in the community forum at https://support.hcltechsw.com/community?id=community_forum&sys_id=cd74744e1b16f340c48197d58d4bcb66

Answer (score 0):

Domino 9.0.1 had its End Of Life in September, 2021.

Fixpacks were never downloadable directly, you always needed to have an active subscription.

HCL put all downloads in their download portal "Flexnet".

If you have a Flexnet- Download- access then you can still download the fixpack there. If you do not have an active subscription then I am afraid there is no legal way for you to get to that. Then you might ask at the support- forum or somebody you know to provide you the software